# Countdown Timer Gets Synced Across all Elements, not Individually

Tags: javascript, html, web, javascript-objects

I have the following script that is a countdown timer that display the hours, minutes, seconds (00:00:00:00) remaining until reaching a specified date. On my HTML page, I have 4 objects that have the timer. The script works, however the timer is the same across all 4 objects, despite each having unique values that should change the countdown. Forgive me as I'm actually working in Webflow, however hopefully it poses no issue:

```
<script>
  // all the objects with the timer
  var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".collection-item");
  wrappers.forEach(function(wrapper) {
    var countDownDate = new Date("July 15, 2023 00:00:00").getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function() {
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // update the HTML elements within the current wrapper
      wrapper.querySelector("#day").innerHTML = days;
      wrapper.querySelector("#hour").innerHTML = hours;
      wrapper.querySelector("#minute").innerHTML = minutes;
      wrapper.querySelector("#second").innerHTML = seconds;

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        carWrapper.querySelector(".announcement").innerHTML = "Yay!";
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

Each object is part of a collection list in Webflow, seen with the following HTML:

```
<div role="listitem" class="collection-item w-dyn-item">
   <a id="000001" href="/books/000001" target="_blank" class="wrapper w-inline-block">
      <h1 class="something">
        <span id="day">00</span>
        <span id="hour">00</span>
        <span id="minute">00</span>
        <span id="second">00</span>
      </h1>
   </a>
      <script>
        script from above here
      </script>
</div>
```

Not sure what's wrong/how to get each timer to run independently for each object. Again, the timer is counting down properly, but all 4 objects are using the time of the 4th object, instead of their own.

Comment: If `countDownDate` is a constant, then they're all counting down to the same thing.  `new Date("date 00:00:00")` is invalid -- what do you really have?

Comment: I have new Date("{{wf {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;date&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;PlainText&quot;\} }} 00:00:00").getTime();
which in Webflow, is linking to the "date" field of the object I have. 

In the end, it ends up showing up in the HTML (inspect element) as var countDownDate = new Date("July 23, 2023 00:00:00").getTime();

Comment: Is the "`script from above here`" repeated with every `.collection-item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with webflow but that appears to be a template fragment that gets rendered once for every item.
You only want your javascript to run once since it is updating every `.collection-item`, **or** have it target only the current item.
I would suggest rendering the date value of the item in a data-attribute and include your script once for the entire collection reading each items value from the html.

```js
// all the objects with the timer
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".collection-item");
wrappers.forEach(function(wrapper) {
  //get the item's data-date
  var countDownDate = new Date(wrapper.querySelector('a').dataset['date']).getTime();

  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // update the HTML elements within the current wrapper
    wrapper.querySelector("#day").innerHTML = days;
    wrapper.querySelector("#hour").innerHTML = hours;
    wrapper.querySelector("#minute").innerHTML = minutes;
    wrapper.querySelector("#second").innerHTML = seconds;

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      carWrapper.querySelector(".announcement").innerHTML = "Yay!";
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div role="listitem" class="collection-item w-dyn-item">
  <a id="000001" href="/books/000001" target="_blank" class="wrapper w-inline-block" data-date="July 15, 2023 00:00:00">
    <h1 class="something">
      <span id="day">00</span>
      <span id="hour">00</span>
      <span id="minute">00</span>
      <span id="second">00</span>
    </h1>
  </a>
</div>
<div role="listitem" class="collection-item w-dyn-item">
  <a id="000001" href="/books/000001" target="_blank" class="wrapper w-inline-block" data-date="July 25, 2023 00:00:00">
    <h1 class="something">
      <span id="day">00</span>
      <span id="hour">00</span>
      <span id="minute">00</span>
      <span id="second">00</span>
    </h1>
  </a>
</div>
<div role="listitem" class="collection-item w-dyn-item">
  <a id="000001" href="/books/000001" target="_blank" class="wrapper w-inline-block" data-date="July 15, 2024 12:30:30">
    <h1 class="something">
      <span id="day">00</span>
      <span id="hour">00</span>
      <span id="minute">00</span>
      <span id="second">00</span>
    </h1>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
  // "script from above" here only once, it should be safe even when the collection is empty
</script>
```